# fillseries vba excel

Tags: vba

i need a help in excel vba

how i want to do fill series in vba
this is my code

```
PackId = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(12, 8).Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ShippingOutput").Range("AD2").Value = PackId
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ShippingOutput").Range("AD2:AD" & iLast).cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
```

output i get is like this

```
AB 0006160000 000000033
AB 0006160000 000000001
AB 0006160000 000000001
AB 0006160000 000000001
AB 0006160000 000000001
AB 0006160000 000000001
AB 0006160000 000000001
AB 0006160000 000000001
AB 0006160000 000000001
```

actually i want the output to bel like this

```
AB 0006160000 000000033
AB 0006160000 000000034
AB 0006160000 000000035
AB 0006160000 000000036
AB 0006160000 000000037
AB 0006160000 000000038
AB 0006160000 000000039
AB 0006160000 000000040
```

Please help.. i already almost give up to do it..

Comment: How are these cells formatted?

Comment: the data actually in text format.. all that in 1 column

Comment: so, how can i add 1 to that value?sorry, i am a beginner

Comment: Either change the format to number or use Val.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ShippingOutput").Range("AD2")
    .autofill destination:=.resize(iLast-1,1)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, you can use the following code:

```
Sub Test2()
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim src As Range, out As Range, SourceRange As Range

lastrow = 20 ' You may recalculate this value.

Set SourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(12, 8)      
'MsgBox SourceRange.Value
Set out = Worksheets("ShippingOutput").Range("AD2")
SourceRange.Copy out

Set fillRange = Worksheets("ShippingOutput").Range("AD2:AD" & lastrow)
out.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange

End Sub
```